# How can I capture screenshot of a screen with a popup in xamarin in Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, popup, screenshot, alert

I need to capture screenshot of DisplayAlert and DisplayActionSheet in Android. Currently it is capturing only the underlying page.

I am using dependency service to capture screenshot.

var rootView = MainActivity.activity.Window.DecorView.RootView;

I need to capture the normal pages as well as pages with popup or atleast capture the popup alone.

Comment: You will need to do it for all open Windows and not only the Activity Window.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron can you please suggest some code

Answer (score 0):

You are very close! Instead of

```
View rootView = MainActivity.activity.Window.DecorView.RootView;
```

Just use the dialog instead of the activity, so

```
View v1 = dialog.Window.DecorView.RootView;
```

And capture that instead

Comment: @Sameer I need to take screenshot of any screen in the app, irrespective of it has a Rg.PluginPopUpPage or display alert or actionsheet or a normal page. In Both iOS and Android.

Comment: In **Android** it does not include the displayalert or displayactionsheet in the screenshot. Takes screenshot of only background page without the pop up. Rg PluginPopUpPage works fine.       In **iOS** it takes screenshot of only foreground popup, and background is black.

Comment: Unfortunately for the dialog to come in the screenshot on Android, its pretty complicated n you would have to build a custom Screenshot interface that implements more code in your Android project. Initially I didn't know you were using Xamarin forms since Xamarin native Android code looked the same